# select row matching exact list of uids

Tags: mysql, query

Given table below

```
id | groupid | memberid
1  | g1      | m1
2  | g1      | m2
3  | g2      | m1
4  | g2      | m2
5  | g2      | m3
```

I'm trying to build a query where I want to get the `groupid` containing exact list of `memberids`.
For example :

Given input as `m1, m2` -> return `g1`

Given input as `m1` -> return nothing

Given input as `m1, m2, m3` -> return `g3`

Assuming it to be a simple social network group table, I'm looking to find a group id containing exact list of member ids.

**What I did :**

I tried building the query using group by, having, count operators but wasn't able to.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT groupid
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT memberid ORDER BY memberid) = 'm1,m2'
```